# T-SQL: search in subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data available in my database:

```
    Docnr   Weight1 Weight2  
    F4879   479,43  484,62  
    F6463   505,43  509,62
    F6464   505,43  509,62
    F8461   531,43  535,62
    F9716   532,43  561,62
    F6461   533,43  561,62
    F6137   609,43  613,62
    F9843   609,43  613,62
    F9764   635,43  613,62
```

Now I want as output an extra column 'Warning' like this:

```
    Docnr   Weight1 Weight2 Warning
    F4879   479,43  484,62  1
    F6463   505,43  509,62  2
    F6464   505,43  509,62  1
    F8461   531,43  535,62  3
    F9716   532,43  561,62  2
    F6461   533,43  561,62  1
    F6137   609,43  613,62  2
    F9843   609,43  613,62  1
    F9764   635,43  613,62
```

Calculation 'Warning': 
`Warning = number of rows ahead where value(Weight2) <= value(Weight1)`

example:

```
   Column 'Warning' in row 1 is 1 because  
   Check 484,62 <= 505,43: Yes -> 1 row ahead    
   Column 'Warning' in row 2 is 2 because   
   Check 509,62 <= 505,43: No  
   Check 509,62 <= 531,43: Yes -> 2 rows ahead  
   Column 'Warning' in row 4 is 3 because   
   Check 535,62 <= 532,43: No  
   Check 535,62 <= 533,43: No  
   Check 535,62 <= 609,43: Yes -> 3 rows ahead
```

Does anybody have a clue how to write my statement to output the above result?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show some effort, SO is not a code generator service. A hint to start with: `CASE ... WHEN`

Comment: How does `Warning` column getting values ? Logic ?

Comment: This query is part of a bigger query. This part I really dont have a clue how to write the statement within a SELECT. Collegues are  advising me to loop and use a counter instead. It's not that I am too lazy to search for a solution...
Column 'Warning' is the calculated column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subquery should work, but requires an order column as a baseline

```
declare @t table (Docnr varchar(10), weight1 float, weight2 float)

insert into @t
values
('F4879', 479.43, 484.62), 
('F6463', 505.43, 509.62), 
('F6464', 505.43, 509.62), 
('F8461', 531.43, 535.62), 
('F9716', 532.43, 561.62), 
('F6461', 533.43, 561.62), 
('F6137', 609.43, 613.62), 
('F9843', 609.43, 613.62), 
('F9764', 635.43, 613.62)


;with r as
(
    select Docnr, weight1, weight2
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by weight1) as nbr
    from @t
)

select r0.nbr, min(r.nbr) - r0.nbr
from r as r0 join r on r0.weight2 < r.weight1
group by r0.nbr
```

Comment: thanx man, this is what i was looking for. Could not find this on my own